# Apollonius problem,a modern approach for beginners

Tags: geometry, reference-request, book-recommendation, plane-curves

The 10 Apollonius problems are to construct all the circles
given 3 of $\{Point,Line,Circle\}$ with repetitions.
So one of them is to construct the 8 (in the generic case) circles touching 3 given circles in the plane.
I have been searching on Amazon for a book `Apollonius problem,a modern approach for beginners`
but it yielded mostly German books. Could anyone suggest to me a suitable work to this ?
At best, pdf from some university site will do. Esp. I wanted to understand (CCC) case, but the other 9 cases are also of interest to me. So I want a complete detailed solution with compass and rule of the 10 cases. Google and YouTube haven't helped much.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: it is in Dorrie, 100 Great Problems of Elementary Mathematics. Translated 1965

Comment: I really like Dorrie. There is an amazing amount of good stuff there.